# Selenium can not click on link form SERP of the google

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here is java class code of test

```
public class Selenium_Test {

    @Test
    public void startWebDriver() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.com");
        Assert.assertEquals("Google", driver.getTitle());
        WebElement searchField = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.gsfi"));
        searchField.sendKeys("datapine.com`");`
        searchField.submit();
        WebElement pricing = driver.findElement(By.linkText(".//a[text() = 'Pricing']"));
        List<WebElement> linkElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='rso']/li"));

        for (WebElement result : linkElements) {
            if (result.equals(pricing)) {
                result.click();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I always get error that Selenium cannot find out element on the page. Can any body help?

Here is stacktrace:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":".//a[text() = 'Pricing']"}
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:340)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By link text locator should be used with a *link text* and not an XPath expression. Replace:

```
By.linkText(".//a[text() = 'Pricing']")
```

with:

```
By.linkText("Pricing")
```

---

You may additionally need to *wait for the element to appear*:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 5);
WebElement pricing = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("Pricing")));
pricing.click();
```

Comment: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Pricing"}

Comment: @Den ok, now it's a different problem. Check the update.